# PHP does not ignore html tags

Tags: php, strip-tags

I have input box in which user entered the string like

```
 "/> <img src=xxx onError=alert('test is here')
```

but at the time of I have used **strip_tags** function before saving the value into the database. It igoners the image tag **but** the string "/> is saved in the database as it is.

How can I overcome with this.

Comment: Because it is not valid HTLM/XML. Why the closing tag is written before?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? Is this for security purposes or because you actually want to extract text from the html? If it's the former you could be better served by encoding/decoding, if it's the latter you may want to use a parser instead.

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish exactly? The tag is stripped, as the function should do (even though it is not closed). The other "thing" `"/>` is not an HTML tag.

Comment: xss attack i guess

Comment: Which **exact** string is remaining? Please share some sample code, inputs, current and expected outputs

Comment: use htmlspecialchars() http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php

Comment: yes.. this is a xss attack.. want to overcome with this

Comment: __escaping output__ is the key.

Comment: I want to save the text only from the string(whatever it is)

Comment: @u_mulder means?

Comment: You can escape it with [htmlspecialchars](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php) so that it is rendered as `<input value="&quot;/&gt;">` for example

Comment: if I use the htmlspecialchars, it saves the value like ""/> <img src=xxx onError=alert('test is here')" as is

Comment: It's not really clear what you are asking. You've given one example of something you don't like, but no explanation. Your description of "save the text only" doesn't really help, `"/>` **is** text. What do you actually want to strip? Anything that isn't a letter or a number? (So forbidding any kind of punctuation). Anything that isn't a dictionary word? (So no people's names). That precise sequence of three characters?

Comment: As an aside you should take a step back and look at the problem you are trying to solve by stripping content from submissions in the first place and ask yourself if this really serves that goal.

Answer (score 0):

To be honest here, there's not one go to solution unfortunately.

The **strip_tags** function works good on well formatted HTML and you example is not a valid one.

One of your options is to write a custom code that "cleans" the input depending on its nature. For example, if the input should collect someones age, strip anything that's not a digit. You can do the same for names, phones, etc. etc.

Of course, we as a developers, can't foreseen all possible non-sense that an user can enter (on purpose or not) and sometimes we end up with such data in the DB. That's why it's always a good idea to escape data before printing it in the HTML. All of the frameworks and template engines out there are already doing it for you. If you're not using a framework you can use **htmlentities** function - http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlentities.php.

The **htmlentities** would make any HTML reserved characters save and won't break you page. For example:

```
htmlentities("/> <img src=xxx onError=alert('test is here')");
```

would result in:

```
/&gt; &lt;img src=xxx onError=alert('test is here')
```

And once rendered via the browser that would look like:

[image]

Comment: yes..exactly.. that should not be.. the string should not be saved in a database in this case..